# 2次元配列のリストを削除したい

Tags: python

2次元配列の要素の削除に困っています。数字の入っていない`[]`の部分を削除したいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
list = [[0,1],[],[],[1,0],[],[],[1,1],[1,2],[],[],[]]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
li=[[0,1],[],[],[1,0],[],[],[1,1],[1,2],[],[],[]]
li = [x for x in li if x]
```

で十分です。
あとPython3ではfilter()が返すのはイテレータです。

Answer (score 6):

本当に list から要素を削除したいのなら

```
for i in range(len(ll) - 1, -1, -1):
  if not ll[i]:
    del ll[i]
```

で出来ます。

ただ、memory は多少とも節約できるかもしれませんが、要素削除のコストがかかるのであまりメリットは無いかもしれません。他の回答にあるように、リスト内包表記を使って新たな list を作る方が短く書けますし、より分かりやすいと思います。

Comment: コスト面ではこのコードが一番綺麗！後ろから削ったのがミソですねぇ。listの要素削除はarrayと違ってリファレンスの更新だけ（とGC）だから、新たにメモリを確保するよりずっと軽いと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！非常に参考になりました。

Comment: 一応計ってみましたが、実行時間の点ではTatz Sekineさんがおっしゃっている通り、だいぶコストがかかるようです。別回答にしておきましたので、参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 気安くこれが一番軽い！何て書いてしまって、恥ずかしい...。実は本当かどうか気になってはいたのですが。

Answer (score 3):

方法による速度の違いが気になったので、みなさんの回答やコメントを参考に実行時間を計りました。
メモリを気にしない場合は、新しいリストを作るほうがよさそうです。

- by_filter
  実行時間が一番短かいのは、`filter`を使った物でした。
- by_comprehension
  内包表記は`filter`より少しだけ遅いですが、あまり変わりません。
- by_loop
  ループで追加していく方法は、`append`が遅いのでしょうか、大分遅いです。
- by_loop_inplace
  新しいリストを作らず要素を削除していく方法は、さらに極端に遅くなります。
  削除対象（空リスト）がどれだけあるかに、実行時間が大きく左右されます。
  しかし、削除対象が殆どなくとも、`filter`や内包表記よりわずかに遅いようです。

以下は50万要素の1/10が空リストである場合の結果です。

```
$ ./del_empty.py 
         450015 function calls in 29.540 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   27.775   27.775   27.775   27.775 del_empty.py:16(by_loop_inplace)
        4    0.000    0.000    1.582    0.395 del_empty.py:22(make_list)
        4    1.582    0.395    1.582    0.395 del_empty.py:23(<listcomp>)
        1    0.095    0.095    0.138    0.138 del_empty.py:3(by_loop)
   450000    0.044    0.000    0.044    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.030    0.030 del_empty.py:10(by_comprehension)
        1    0.030    0.030    0.030    0.030 del_empty.py:11(<listcomp>)
        1    0.015    0.015    0.015    0.015 del_empty.py:13(by_filter)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method len}
```

del_empty.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

def by_loop(target_list):
    new_list = []
    for v in target_list:
        if v:
            new_list.append(v)
    return new_list

def by_comprehension(target_list):
    return [x for x in target_list if x]

def by_filter(target_list):
    return list(filter(None, target_list))

def by_loop_inplace(target_list):
    for i in range(len(target_list) - 1, -1, -1):
        if not target_list[i]:
            del target_list[i]
    return target_list

def make_list():
    return [[x, 0] if x % 10 else [] for x in range(500000)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import cProfile
    pr = cProfile.Profile()
    pr.enable()

    by_loop(make_list())
    by_comprehension(make_list())
    by_filter(make_list())
    by_loop_inplace(make_list())

    pr.disable()
    pr.print_stats(sort="cumtime")
```

Comment: [TimeComplexy Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)によるとlistの`.append`はなんとO(1), `del`はO(n)だそうです。

Comment: `pop`はO(1)という記述が[内部実装の解説](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/)にありますが、delをpopに置き換えてもやっぱり遅いままでした。ちなみにスロットという内部のarrayがあり、要素の追加削除はarrayの操作が行われるので遅いらしい。理解できるまで読んでみます。

Comment: よく考えたら、appendがO(1)なのは当たり前。配列の走査をするわけでもないんだから。だから目的の操作の時間は要素数に比例してO(n)。削除は毎回リストを辿るからO(n)それに要素数がかかるからO(n^2)。こりゃ遅いわけだ。

Answer (score 2):

Python2.7

```
>>> l=[[0,1],[],[],[1,0],[],[],[1,1],[1,2],[],[],[]]
>>> filter(None, l)
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python2.7

```
>>> list = filter(lambda x: x != [], list)
>>> list
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`list`は Python が標準で使っているので、上書きするのは避けた方がよいです。
（ただの変数ではあるので、分かってやっているなら構わないですが）
以下では "`li`" としておきます。

追記: Kenji Noguchiさんのコメントを受け、`[]`との比較を止めて、空のシーケンスが False であることを利用したコードにしました。

基本は新しいリストを作りそれに追加していき、出来たら"`li`"をその新しいリストに束縛する形になると思います。

```
li = [[0,1],[],[],[1,0],[],[],[1,1],[1,2],[],[],[]]
new_li = []

for v in li:
    if v:
        new_li.append(v)
li = new_li
```

内包表記バージョン(argusさんの回答とほぼ同じ事をしています)

```
li = [[0,1],[],[],[1,0],[],[],[1,1],[1,2],[],[],[]]

li = [x for x in li if x]
```

新しいリストを作らずやると以下のようにごちゃごちゃしますし、これで性能がよくなる事もないと思います。（メモリが厳しい場合は分かりませんが）

追記: Tatz Sekineさんの回答でリストの末尾から見ていく方法が紹介されています。あちらの方が断然いいです。
追記: 実行時間を計測しました。長いので別回答にしましたが、要素の削除は思ったよりずっと遅かったです。

```
li = [[0,1],[],[],[1,0],[],[],[1,1],[1,2],[],[],[]]

del_count = 0
for i in range(len(li)):
    i -= del_count
    if not li[i]:
        del li[i]
        del_count += 1
```

Comment: inplaceでの操作に言及した点で+1。 `v != [] `と `v == [] `はPythonの熟語としては`not v`あるいは`v`と書くのが良いとされています。PEP8参照。あえて空のリストオブジェクトを作る必要もありません。

Comment: なるほど、ループの度にリストが生成されるのはよくないですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。